# iOS Facebook 4.0 SDK Share OpenGraph story with UIImage error

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, uiimage

I am in need of posting an OpenGraph story that contains a user generated image, without requesting any permissions.

I have followed the official tutorial posted here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/ios

And here is my code:

```
NSDictionary *properties = @{@"og:type": @"minidraw-two.illustration",
                                     @"og:title": @"Illustration",
                                     @"og:description": @"iOS Vector illustration app"};
FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject *object = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject objectWithProperties:properties];

// Construct an FBSDKSharePhoto
FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
photo.image = image;
photo.userGenerated = YES;

FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction *action = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction actionWithType:@"minidraw-two.create" object:object key:@"minidraw-two:illustration"];
[action setPhoto:photo forKey:@"image"];

FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent *content = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent new];
content.action = action;
content.previewPropertyName = @"minidraw-two:illustration";

[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:viewController
                                     withContent:content
                                        delegate:self];
```

When posting this content, I am getting the following error:

> Error Domain=com.facebook.Facebook.platform Code=100 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.Facebook.platform error 100.)"
>   UserInfo=0x174070f00 {error_reason=Missing either 'type' or
>   'fbsdk:create_object' for object: image, error_description=An error
>   occurred while sharing an action., app_id=,
>   error_code=100}

I am not really sure what this error means. I have checked StackOverflow, the Facebook docs and found nothing.

Please advice.

Comment: Hi @Cristian, any update or resolution?

Comment: No, sadly nothing. Only option I have for now is to use the non-story image sharing.

Answer (score 4):

After reading [this FB bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/783342808381646/), I've got the photo to be shared without any errors. The key is to attach the photo to the Open Graph **object** rather than the **action**.

```
// Add the photo to the OG object
[object setPhoto:photo forKey:@"og:image"];
```

The photo is still not showing full-width, but that has been recognized by FB as a valid bug in v4.0.1 and I will update this answer as soon as I hear more from them.

UPDATE: According to FB, it is by design that photos will not show full-width on Open Graph stories.

Comment: The documentation is sorely broken then, the code snippets all set the `image` field of the Facebook action rather than the object!

Comment: And no, I don't think it's by design — design clearly states that images which are qualified as user generated (`userGenerated:YES`) should be shown wide! The photo should definitely be attache to the action, and it should definitely be wide even for an open graph story. See http://designerhubinc.blogspot.com/2012/06/user-generated-photos-in-open-graph.html for an image.

Answer (score 0):

If You change

`[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:viewController withContent:content delegate:self];`

to

`[FBSDKShareAPI shareWithContent:content delegate:self];`

and use your old variant `[action setPhoto:photo forKey:@"image"];` the code will also work

Comment: But that would mean the content is shared without showing the share dialog, right?  The `FBSDKShareAPI` is intended for custom UI's... so if you really wanted the convenience of using `FBSDKShareDialog` then there are no options. :/

Answer (score 0):

2 fatuhoku - on my opinion use `FBSDKShareAPI` is better because
1) your app does not switch to FB app to present dialog
2) you control all the data you want to share/post in FB from your app. For example my app shares only it's internal data and i don't want user to add comment to it in the dialog.
3) you keep the UI style of your app for example screen colors but FB dialogs has there own.
Yes, you should do more work then when using `FBSDKShareDialog` but read what i say above ;)

Comment: Do you have examples/blogs/gist etc. on how you did this? Facebook's doc does not give much in terms of custom story.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed. Both `FBSDKShareDialog` and `FBSDKShareAPI` work the same now. Relevant bug report [here](https://developers.intern.facebook.com/bugs/1581589682118026/). Official docs updated as well.